# How can I separate out the Ids in tables joined within a Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I have the following that joins together 3 tables, Images, Users, Profiles. The problem I have is that the result of the following only gives me 1 id field and that is the Id of the Profiles table. All 3 tables have their own Id fields.

Can I seperate it so that it is images.id, profiles.id and users.id?

```
$images = \App\Image::where('image_approved', '=' ,"feature_approved")
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'images.user_id')
            ->join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'images.user_id')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alias them like this:

```
$images = \App\Image::select([
                'users.id as user_id',
                'profiles.id as profile_id',
                'images.id as image_id',
                //... add the rest of the columns that you want to select here.
            ])
            ->where('image_approved', '=' ,"feature_approved")
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'images.user_id')
            ->join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'images.user_id')
            ->get();
```

or you can simplify it by using Eloquent relationships.

So in your `Image` model you would have:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Profile::class, User::class);
}
```

Then you can retrieve them:

```
$images = Image::with('user', 'profile')
               ->where('image_approved', '=' ,"feature_approved")
               ->get();

// now each $image in $images will have user and profile relationship

// $image->id
// $image->user->id
// $image->profile->id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use alias in select like this:

```
->join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'images.user_id')
->select('images.*', 'users.*', 'profiles.*', 'images.id as imageID', 'profiles.id as profileId', 'users.id as usersId')
->get();
```