# How to joining Table in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I have 2 table users and data .

> in users table have :

id | name |email | etc

> in data table have :

id | user_id | no_data | etc

i create model Data like this

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->HasMany(\App\User::class ,'id');
}
```

my Controller :

```
public function pns()
{
    $data = Data::get();

    //DB::table('data')
        //->join('users','data.user_id','=','users.id')
        //->where(['user' => 'something', 'otherThing' => 
         // 'otherThing'])
        //->get(); // i trying to join this table but still error 


    return view('admin.data',['data' => $data]);
}
```

now i want to show view data in table :

on my view blade :

```
 <th>No </th>
 <th>id </th>
 <th>Name </th>
 <th>email </th>


  @php
  $no=0;
  @endphp
  @foreach ($data as $i)
  <tr>
   <td class=" ">{{ ++$no }}</td>
   <td class=" ">{{ $i->user_id}}</td>
   <td class=" ">{{ $i->users->name}}</td>
   <td class=" ">{{ $i->email}}</td>
  </tr>
```

this user_id is showed ,but this 'name' is cant showed and get error :

Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

edited my dd($data)

```
#attributes: array:18 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "user_id" => 6
    "email" => 'q@gmail.com'
    //etc
    "created_at" => "2019-06-18 17:27:54"
    "updated_at" => "2019-06-18 17:27:54"
  ]
```

Comment: You can alias the fields you want, or you can simplify it by using Eloquent relationships https://stackoverflow.com/a/56656399/7498116

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, your one user can have multiple data. Here is my solution

For **User Modal**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

  <YOUR OTHER CODES HERE>

  public function datas(){
     return $this->hasMany(Data::class,'user_id','id');
  }
}
```

For **Data.php** [ Data modal]

```
class Data extends Model{

 <YOUR OTHER CODE>

 public function userDetail(){
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
 }
}
```

From your controller:

```
 $data = Data:with('userDetail')->get();
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($data->toArray()); // This will give you an array of data with user details.
```

Comment: can you tell me why you used HasMany on datas Modal ? I am really didnt know

Comment: This is based on the assumption that one `user` can have many `datas`. If thats not the case then it will change.

Answer (score 0):

do this `$data = Data::with('users')->get();`

Comment: still error . my view using this {{ $i->users->name}}

Comment: do a `dd($data)` and check if the data is being retrieved

Comment: $data = Data_pns::with('users')->get();  , now i dd($data); . but not showed atributes name . i update my dd($data) on my thread

Answer (score 0):

Use this Query

```
DB::table('data')
->join('users','data.user_id','=','users.id')
->where('user_id','=',1)
// Here you can also add more wheres
// But make sure where column exists in one of queried table i.e in 
// users | data 
->select([
    'no',
    'user_id as id',
    'name',
    'email'   
])
->get(); // i trying to join this table but still error
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your relationship in data model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\User::class ,'user_id');
}
```

it should be **hasMany** not **HasMany** and **user_id** not **id**

Then use this: `$data = Data::with('users')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

use hasOne in your User model

```
public function data()
{
return $this->hasOne('App\Data', 'user_id');
}
```

//controller

```
return view('admin.data')->with($data);
```